# net use \\server\printer_name does not show in Device and printer

Tags: printing, network-printer, cups

I used the command

```
net use \\server\printer_name
```

To mount a cups shared printer into my client computer.

This printer is visible with the command

```
net use
```

but still not visible neither in the printing dialogs nor the "Device and Printer" screen.

How can I make this printer available for printing?

Answer (score 0):

This page should get you going basically CUPs is NOT the same as Windows printer sharing you need to in a BROWSER access your servers CUPs server  via either IP or DNS.  easiest is IP as shown in the guide link I am pasting below.

Even though this states for Windows 8 with only slight modifications for different util names and all it can be used on Windows 7 or Vista prolly:
http://www.gigamegablog.com/2012/09/03/adding-a-linux-cups-printer-to-windows-8/